# Appcelerator Notification createRemoteViews click event listener

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am trying to build a music player, for which I need to have music control in Notification tray.
I am using RemoteViews for this But not able to add event listener for Play/Pause, Next and Previous.
Below is the source code.

custom_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_logo"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/app_logo_notification"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/lbl_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="#b8a25e"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="TEST" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#b8a25e"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Now Playing James Bond anthem"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_previous"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_previous_home"/>
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_play"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_playback_play"/>
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_next"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_next_home"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Notification code -

```
    var AppR = Ti.App.Android.R;
    var customLayout = Ti.Android.createRemoteViews({
        layoutId : AppR.layout.custom_layout
    });
    var notification = Titanium.Android.createNotification({
        contentView : customLayout,
        visibility : Titanium.Android.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC,
        icon : AppR.drawable.app_logo_notification,
    });


    customLayout.setTextViewText(AppR.id.message, "Now Playing...\n");
    customLayout.setImageViewResource(AppR.id.icon_play, AppR.drawable.ic_action_playback_pause);
    var icon_play = AppR.id.icon_play;
    Ti.Android.NotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a full example of a RemoteView Notification at:
https://docs.axway.com/bundle/Titanium_SDK_allOS_en/page/android_notifications.html#AndroidNotifications-Customlayout
that features buttons and click events.

In your example it should be:

```
customLayout.setOnClickPendingIntent(Ti.App.Android.R.id.icon_play, onClickCallback);

function onClickCallback(){}
```

Comment: I have already tried this, it crashes application.
setOnClickPendingIntent is expecting a pending intent